# How to automatically clean hollow lines in middle of polygons in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, geometry, v.clean

I am trying to correct automatically this kind of errors. I already tried the tools v.clean (maybe I have to tune some parameters?) and correct geometries. I also tried dissolving, but since there is space between polygons It does not work.
Obviously, the polygons at each side of hollow lines have the same attributes.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Not a real solution more an idea. Creating a convex hull from all your polygon and then substract to try to create the missing gaps due to your hollow lines can help? Second issue would be how to cut them to "reattach" them to polygons sharing the same attributes.

Comment: Perhaps some kind of raster "grow" followed by an equal "shrink". The gaps will fill with the grow, but won't shrink since they will no longer be the edges.

Comment: As the polygons to be mergerd have the same attribute, you could try using aggregate: https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html?#aggregate - By the way: for such questions, it would be really helpful to provide your data (or a sample of it) for testing.